# Bluetooth sound lags under Mint 18

Tags: linux-mint, bluetooth

I have a HP Pavilion DV-7 laptop running Linux Mint 18 x64 and Edifier R1700BT speakers. I have no problem pairing speakers to laptop, but when I'm trying to play some mp3 files sound in speakers extremely lags, just like it's a very slow internet connection when you streaming something online. 
But if I boot the same laptop with Linux Mint 15 from USB, then BT works just perfectly. I've copied all *.conf files from /etc/bluetooth from Mint 15 to Mint 18 but it doesn't help.
Please help to make BT sound work perfectly.